# Unable to view notification Icon in ionic application

Tags: push-notification, ionic3

I am using push notification plugin in ionic 3 => https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/
, but a gray icon appears as a notification app icon. please suggest how to fix this.
[Here is screensort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJGyi.jpg)

Comment: you need to change your app icon to transparent png and check after that your problem is solve

Comment: Thanks, It's working.